# How to delete cells from list but keep her len python

Tags: python, list

I want to delete all the same cells but because of changes in my list the length is changing as well so instead of 9 loops it makes 5.

For the input:

`apple,banana,coconut,apple,banana,coconut,apple,banana,coconut(str)`

I expect the output:

`apple, banana, coconut (list)`

but I got:

`banana, apple, banana, coconut`

I tried to make another list so it won't change the original list length but as you can understand it hasn't helped.

Can you help, please?

P.S I made the string to a list(list_of_products)

```
just_a_list = list_of_products
for product in just_a_list:
    if list_of_products.count(product) > 1:
        list_of_products.remove(product)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), which by definition, is:

> an unordered collection with no duplicate elements

```
x = ['apple','banana','coconut','apple','banana','coconut','apple','banana','coconut']
print(set(x))
```

Output:

```
{'apple', 'coconut', 'banana'}
```

If you want it as a list:

```
>>> unique = list(set(x))
['coconut', 'apple', 'banana']
```

Comment: Ok thank you so just for the protocol set means to make the list with any duplication?

Comment: @CaptainPython as long as the list contains hashable elements, yes.

Comment: wait but if want to use that list for any other uses it ain't working.

Comment: You have to assign it to a variable to use it. so `use_this = list(set(list_of_products))`

Comment: I mean i want to print that list so it prints me the original even thought i made x = set(x)

Comment: Bruv have you checked it up?

Comment: It couldn't see anything wrong with it.  You assign to a set correctly.  When I select option 8, it correctly shows the list without duplicates.

Comment: yes but it supposed to be continuing like option 8 the delete and then option 1 print after delete

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve this is simply converting the list to a set and then to a list again.

```
list_of_products = ["apple", "banana", "coconut", "apple", "banana", "coconut", "apple", "banana", "coconut"]
products = list(set(list_of_products))
# products = ['coconut', 'apple', 'banana']
```